# URL Escaping with Unity (Firebase URL)

Tags: url, unity-game-engine, firebase, escaping, firebase-storage

I am trying to download a image stored in the Firebase Storage, using Unity. I use Unity Firebase SKD (in Beta...). This is my code:

```
 ...
 // Points to "1/preview.jpg"
    Firebase.Storage.StorageReference img_ref = folder1_ref.Child("/preview.jpg");

// Fetch the download URL
img_ref.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
    Debug.Log(task.Result.ToString());
    });
```

The console output is:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/insidehome-29c9e.appspot.com/o/1/preview.jpg?alt=media&token=092a8de8-5047-4bce-b179-edd4101847a3
```

If I try to download the file using www or a browser, with this URL, I obtain an error. The good URL should be (copied by Firebase console):

```
https%3A%2F%2Ffirebasestorage.googleapis.com%2Fv0%2Fb%2Finsidehome-29c9e.appspot.com%2Fo%2F1%2Fpreview.jpg%3Falt%3Dmedia%26token%3D092a8de8-5047-4bce-b179-edd4101847a3
```

The difference is only in a single slash ("/") before the word "preview".

Is this strange? How could I fix it? I try Escape the URL but it change all the slash:

```
https%3A%2F%2Ffirebasestorage.googleapis.com%2Fv0%2Fb%2Finsidehome-29c9e.appspot.com%2Fo%2F1%2F99%2Fobama.jpg%3Falt%3Dmedia%26token%3D8a33f998-e271-4d7e-8848-356a332b7750
```

And It does't work. I need to change only the parameters (right) slash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Firebase engineer here.  This is a bug and I'm sorry you encountered this.  There should be no slash after "/o/".  The 2 slashes surrounding the letter "o" are valid, but every forward slash after that should be displayed as %2F.

This is not a general escaping issue as you should not re-escape the entire URL.  This is a side effect of a related mono issue in unity where the Uri class incorrectly decodes %2F into a slash when it shouldn't.

You can work around this by simply replacing slashes *after* "/o/" with %2F.  However, you should know about a corresponding issue with UnityWebRequest:

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/unitywebrequest-dot-url-unescapes-escaped-symbol

where Unity's libraries are also being affected by this bug (so it may break even if you fix the string and pass it back to unity).  It looks like that issue was fixed in 5.5.1 (and I've verified it in 5.6 beta).

On the firebase side, we will change our code to account for this issue in mono so it returns the correct url.  Until we get this fix out, I suggest using the workaround of replacing slashes or simply use Firebase itself to download the file.

Comment: Also, try using uri.OriginalString -- which returns the string as it was before the Uri decided to "fix" it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unity's [`WWW.EscapeURL`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.EscapeURL.html) to escape url.

```
string escapedUrl = WWW.EscapeURL("http://www.someurl");
```

Comment: this is a good answer to escape a url, but in this particular case you should not re-escape the entire url, just the decoded slashes.

Comment: @BenjaminWulfe What happens when you re-escape the entire url?

Comment: Since the url is actually already escaped (except for the decoded slashes), you'll end up re-encoding escape sequences so they become double encoded. So a url-encoded space (%20) might end up as %2520 -- which is not what you want.

Comment: @BenjaminWulfe I tried that to see if that's the case and yes, you are right. I will delete this post once you  see this comment.

Comment: Thanks for double checking!